# boost::asio::co_spawn is undefined in MSVC

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, asio

I am attempting to create a TCP server using boost.asio and following the examples you use co_spawn to start the listener function in a new thread.

When I try to use `boost::asio::co_spawn` Microsoft Visual Studios tells me it is undefined, I have included all files the [boost example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp17/coroutines_ts/echo_server.cpp) does.

TcpServer.h

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/asio/co_spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/detached.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_context.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/signal_set.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/write.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/coroutine.hpp>

using namespace boost::asio;

class TcpServer
{
public:
    TcpServer(int port);
    ~TcpServer();
private:

};
```

TcpServer.cpp

```cpp
#include "TcpServer.h"


/*
    Create a TcpServer on a given port
*/
TcpServer::TcpServer(int port)
{
    io_context ioCtx(1);

    /* E0020    identifier "co_spawn" is undefined  */
    co_spawn();
}


TcpServer::~TcpServer()
{
}
```

The above code tells me that `co_spawn` is undefined, I have searched other name spaces and checked for alternative functions and there is none. I thought maybe it was outdated documentation but the `boost.asio` reference for version `1.70.1` still lists `co_spawn` as a free function. See [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/co_spawn.html)

I am using
Boost: 1.70.1
Microsoft Visual Studio 2017: v15.9.7

Comment: do you need a command line option on msvc to enable coroutines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

boost.asio has preprocessor code to detect the capabilities of the compiler and only turn on coroutine support if the compiler supports it.

For MSVC, I think you will need to add the compiler flag `/await` to the compiler command line option list.

reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/await-enable-coroutine-support?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly and the documentation link was very helpful! I am surprised I couldn't find something on that through all my Google searches and documentation reading.

Comment: @ImpossibleMushroom I only knew where to look because I happened to read some of the new ASIO source code yesterday as I want to use co_routines to simplify our production code too.